# JavaFX: How to handle text selection on textField with event handler?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a javaFX text field with the following event handler:

```
public static EventHandler<KeyEvent> numericValidation(final Integer maxLengh) {
    return new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
            TextField txt_TextField = (TextField) e.getSource();

            if (txt_TextField.getText().length() >= max_Lengh) {
                e.consume();
            }
            if(!e.getCharacter().matches("[0-9]")){
                e.consume();
            }
        }
    };
}
...
yearTextField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED , numeric_Validation(4));
```

This should make sure that the text field can only take numbers with at most `maxLength` digits. The problem is that now if I select some of the text from the text field (some digits) and I try to write other digits, it wont do anything. I want the selected text to be replaced with what I'm writing, just like it does with basic text fields, as long as it is digits and wont exceed the length of `maxLength`.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `TextFormatter` created using a `UnaryOperator` as constructor parameter. This `UnaryOperator` receives a object containing, among other info, the new text that would result from the input. You can return a modified change influencing the outcome or simply return `null` for the input not to modify the `TextField`.

Using this approach your code also works, if you copy&paste multiple digits to the `TextField`...

Example:

```
int maxLength = 8;
final String matchString = "\\d{0," + maxLength + "}"; // allow 0 to maxLength digits

TextField textField = new TextField();
TextFormatter<?> formatter = new TextFormatter<>(change -> {
    String newText = change.getControlNewText();
    return newText.matches(matchString) ? change : null;
});
textField.setTextFormatter(formatter);
```

Comment: Works perfectly.